# Execute Background Task In Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I have a cpu intensive task that I need to run on the client.   Ideally, I'd like to be able to invoke the function and trigger progress events using jquery so I can update the UI.

I know javascript does not support threading, but I've seen a few promising articles trying to mimic threading using setTimeout.

What is the best approach to use for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar problem to solve recently where i needed to keep my UI thread free while crunching some data to display.

I wrote a library Background.js to handle a few scenarios: a sequential background queue (based on the WorkerQueue library), a list of jobs where each is called on every timer, and an array iterator to help break up your work into smaller chunks. Examples and code here: https://github.com/kmalakoff/background

Enjoy!

Answer (score 40):

Basically, what you want to do is to divide the operation into pieces. So say you have 10 000 items you want to process, store them in a list and then process a small number of them with a small delay between each call. Here's a simple structure you could use:

```
function performTask(items, numToProcess, processItem) {
    var pos = 0;
    // This is run once for every numToProcess items.
    function iteration() {
        // Calculate last position.
        var j = Math.min(pos + numToProcess, items.length);
        // Start at current position and loop to last position.
        for (var i = pos; i < j; i++) {
            processItem(items, i);
        }
        // Increment current position.
        pos += numToProcess;
        // Only continue if there are more items to process.
        if (pos < items.length)
            setTimeout(iteration, 10); // Wait 10 ms to let the UI update.
    }
    iteration();
}

performTask(
    // A set of items.
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'],
    // Process two items every iteration.
    2,
    // Function that will do stuff to the items. Called once for every item. Gets
    // the array with items and the index of the current item (to prevent copying
    // values around which is unnecessary.)
    function (items, index) {
        // Do stuff with items[index]
        // This could also be inline in iteration for better performance.
    });
```

Also note that [Google Gears has support to do work on a separate thread](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html). Firefox 3.5 also introduced [its own workers that do the same thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) (although they follow [the W3 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), while Google Gears uses its own methods.)

Comment: Thanks. This worked very well for me, but I was working with an array of data so it might not be the best solution for everyone.

Comment: Won't work for an existing control like a tree view that doesn't support breaking down a task like updating the tree, which involves iterating over every node.

Answer (score 10):

If you can enforce the browser to be used, or you otherwise already know it to be a new version of Firefox, you could use the new [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) from Mozilla. It allows you to spawn new threads.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what your requirements are, you may get off easily by using Gears. Gears supports threads, which could do what you want.

As you mentioned, setTimeout is the other option. Depending on the type of your task, you can hand off each iteration of a loop to a separate setTimeout call with some spacing in between, or you may need to separate pieces of your main algorithm into separate functions which can be called one by one in a same manner as you'd call each iteration.

Comment: +1, but gears 'workers' aren't exactly what other environment calls 'threads'.

Comment: Firefox 3.5 also has W3 standardized workers. See my answer for links.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution to the problem, in case someone wants simple copy-pasteable piece of code:

```
    let iterate = function (from, to, action, complete) {
        let i = from;
        let impl = function () {
            action(i);
            i++;
            if (i < to) setTimeout(impl, 1);
            else complete();
        };
        impl();
    };
```

Comment: That saved life!!

Answer (score 3):

Great answer Kevin!  I wrote something similar a few years back, though less sophisticated.  Source code is here if anyone wants it:

http://www.leapbeyond.com/ric/jsUtils/TaskQueue.js

Anything with a `run()` method can be queued as a task.  Tasks can re-queue themselves to perform work in chunks.  You can prioritize tasks, add/remove them at will, pause / resume the entire queue, etc.  Works well with asynchronous operations - my original use for this was to manage several concurrent XMLHttpRequests.

Basic usage is pretty simple:

```
var taskQueue = new TaskQueue();
taskQueue.schedule("alert('hello there')");
```

The header comments in the .js file provide more advanced examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example of how to create threads in JavaScript.
Note that is is up to you to interrupt your thread functions (yeld instruction). If you want, you can use a setTimeout instead of my *while* loop to run the scheduler periodically.
Note also that this example only works with JavaScript version 1.7+ (firefox 3+)
you can try it here: http://jslibs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jseval.html

```
//// thread definition
function Thread( name ) {

    for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

        Print(i+' ('+name+')');
        yield;
    }
}

//// thread management
var threads = [];

// thread creation
threads.push( new Thread('foo') );
threads.push( new Thread('bar') );

// scheduler
while (threads.length) {

    var thread = threads.shift();
    try {
        thread.next();
        threads.push(thread);
    } catch(ex if ex instanceof StopIteration) { }
}
```

The output is:

```
0 (foo) 0 (bar) 1 (foo) 1 (bar) 2 (foo) 2 (bar) 3 (foo) 3 (bar) 4 (foo) 4 (bar)
```

Comment: That's really neat although not feasible unless the user can be forced to use Firefox 3+. `=)` I really like your JavaScript evaluator though, I'll bookmark that one! `=)`

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Perhaps you could have a look at the jslibs project: http://code.google.com/p/jslibs

Answer (score 0):

My strongest recommendation is to display a simple loading.gif during the operation. User often accepts some duration if they have been "told" that it could take some time.

[Ajaxload - Ajax loading gif generator](http://www.ajaxload.info)

Answer (score 0):

use `requestIdleCallback()`.

Then you will use the browsers idle time to process your task.

Sample found in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API

Answer (score 0):

there is a feature (experimental when I am writing):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback

seems not real multithread, but execute the task with low priority than the other (UI) tasks

so the solution can be:

1. make your task asynchronous
2. start your task with this
   requestIdleCallback
3. loop using a setTimeout() with microtimes in your task, like between some main loop and his inner logic

the UI can update frequently in these timeouts

Answer (score -2):

Seems this problem has been solved in node itself.

require child_process which is included in nodejs 0.10.4