# Javascript while loop makes the page not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, while-loop

When I put this in my header:

```
<script>
function checkiffinished() {
  var n = $('.result-row').length;
  while (n!==3)
  {
  n = $('.result-row').length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  };

  };
</script>
```

Then in the body put

```
<script>
 checkiffinished();
 </script>
```

then the page crashes.

The code is supposed to count the number of divs with the "result-row" class and repeat that until the number of divs with aforementioned class is 3.

How can I make it so as such and not crash the page?

EDIT 1: other jQuery I have in the page causes there to be .result-row elements on another event, that's why I need it to check periodically.

EDIT2 : I'm trying to run this in parallel with some other jQuery that manipulates the elements on the page.

Comment: `n` never increases, are there any `.result-row` elements added at all?

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash page'? Does the browser freeze? Why are re-assigning `n` with the same value within the loop?

Comment: other jquery i have in the page causes there to be .result-row elements on another event, that's why i need it to check periodically.

Comment: The `while` loop will block any other execution of code.

Comment: You are not delaying the iterations of the while loop. Give the browser some room to breathe for heaven's sake `:)` (use a timer or something)

Comment: Have you defined checkiffinished ?

Comment: I would create a custom jQuery event, then fire it in the OTHER code to instantiate a check, and do whatever is needed within that check (or exit back if not ready yet).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript can only run one piece of code at a time. So your `while` loop is clogging up all JavaScript execution. As a result, any code that adds elements is suspended - basically forever.

Instead, you might want to use an interval which checks e.g. each second: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/sbs6m/1/.

```
function checkiffinished() {
  var n = $('.result-row').length;
  $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  if(n === 3) {
    // do something
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
};

var interval = setInterval(checkiffinished, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 second
```

Comment: That would work but if his function is wrong it would still freeze the page.

Comment: @Will Evans: His `while` loop was freezing the page. This code does not have any infinite loops.

Comment: the page loads but then freezes (by freezes i mean that none of the other jquery elements function)

Comment: @Josh: Does the fiddle also freeze?

Comment: @Josh: Maybe your jQuery is not correct. And don't use the term freeze if it is actually not freezing.

Comment: So if he needs it to run in the background then surely he should use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160137/execute-background-task-in-javascript

Comment: @Felix Kling  the jQuery is correct and functions perfectly if i take out the javascript i'm trying to fix currently

Comment: @Josh: Then maybe if you provide a jsfiddle demo we are able to help more.

Comment: @Josh: primvdb's fiddle works perfectly fine for me (did you click the `add` button?)... which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that n is not decremented.

pimvdb's Idea is a good one. Here is an implementation that includes a callback:

```
 var waitUntil = function (fn, condition, interval) {
    interval = interval || 100;

    var shell = function () {
            var timer = setInterval(
                function () {
                    var check;

                    try { check = !!(condition()); } catch (e) { check = false; }

                    if (check) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        delete timer;
                        fn();
                    }
                },
                interval
            );
        };

    return shell;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
waitUntil(
  function () {
    // the code you want to run here...
  },
  function() {
    // the code that tests here... (return true if test passes; false otherwise)
  },
  0 // amout to wait between checks
)();
```

Comment: How does this help here? Can you give an example? What is `All`?

Comment: Mmmh. Your code is supposed to iterate over an array and do something with each element. I don't see how this can be applied to checking periodically how many elements of a certain type exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an infinite loop if `n !== 3` because nothing you do in the while loop ever changes the value of n so the `while` loop just runs forever waiting for the value of n to become 3.  It is unclear why you put it in a `while` loop.  It looks to me like it should just be an `if` instead of a `while`.

```
<script>
function checkiffinished() {
  var n = $('.result-row').length;
  if (n!==3)
  {
    $("span").text("There are " + n + " divs.");
  };

}
</script>
```

If you are going to use a while loop, then you have to have something that actually changes the value of n in the loop and code that ensures that you will reach the condition in your while loop to prevent the infinite loop.

As others have said, if you want to regularly check for the value of 3, then you need to repeatedly execute this function using setTimeout or setInterval not just loop infinitely.  But, you don't want to execute it to often or you may drag down the performance of your site and other pages in the browser.

The best performing way to implement this would be just manually call `checkiffinished()` any time you've modified the page.  That way, no browser cycles would be wasted regularly checking the page value when nothing has changed and the page would be updated immediately after the change (no waiting for the next timer to fire to check the page).

Answer (score 0):

Urmm, try making a button and see if it calls it and doesn't crash e.g  `<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="checkiffinished()" />`

Comment: when i click the button it freezes the page.

Comment: Oh try using an interval instead.