# CSS transitions and browser tabs

Tags: javascript, css, window, focus, transition

This is a really weird problem:

I have a circle that keeps rotating indefinitely with CSS rotate transition, to keep it rotating indefinitely I am using jquery to keep changing the rotate value every 30 sec to a bigger value. I found this to be smoother visually than full CSS solutions.

Yet I have noticed that css transition behaves like this: 
It stops even if the transition is not finished when window > tab > page > element has another tab active or if the window is minimized.

So jquery goes on, but the transition stop, making the rotation increase in speed. Stopping the jquery function that increase the rotation when the tab is not focused helps, but not solves the problem entirely because in scenarios where the element is "visible" but the tab is not focused (think of the tab opened but another program is active above the browser, or another window of the browser is open maybe in a tile) the transition keeps going but the jquery timer stops, making the circle stop itself eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a transition for this?

```
#yourElement {
    animation:spin 10s linear;
    -webkit-animation:spin 10s linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:none}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform:none}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)}
}
```

This will animate smoothly and flawlessly, even with tab switches.

Comment: this is good, but if you want to rotate an element that has already a default rotation you would have to create an animation for each element with different from{} values.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a background task to refresh the CSS. Check out this thread: [Execute Background Task In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160137/execute-background-task-in-javascript)