# Massive for loop taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, for-loop, primes

I'm working on a program designed to generate prime numbers, and I'm trying to find the 10001st prime number. Each time the loop runs, it tests variable i to see if it's divisible by variable j, which is part of another loop that goes up to half of i. If i is divisible by j then it adds one to variable prime, and when the loop's done it checks to see if variable prime is larger than two; if it is, then i is not prime. If it is prime, it gets push()ed to the variable array, which stores all the primes. Sorry if that's a little confusing.

My problem is that although this code works, whenever I set the first for loop too high (here I have it end at 100000), my browser freezes:

```
var prime = 0;
var array = [];
for(var i = 2; i <= 100000; i+=1) {
  var prime = 0;
  for(var j = 0; j <= i/2; j+=1) {
    if(i % j === 0) {
      prime += 1;
    }
  }

  if(prime < 2) {
    array.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(array.length)
```

I know I could just copy and paste all the prime numbers but I want to make the program work. Any ideas to make the program stop freezing?

Comment: The algorithm you're using is just too inefficient. There's not much  you can do other than use a better algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160137/execute-background-task-in-javascript

Comment: use square root method to solve. so number of iteration will be reduced

Comment: Try implementing this algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes ..Its quick, and an example of dynamic programming

Comment: Ok, I take back what I said. You can make this 10 times faster if you add `if( prime === 2 ) break;` inside the inner loop. http://jsfiddle.net/reumzot5/

Comment: Why go all the way to `i/2`? You can stop at `Math.sqrt(i)`. Also, you can skip all even values of `j`. Also, why does `j` start at 0? Start at 3 instead. Also, your loop keeps going after a prime factor has already been found, use `break` instead.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12287599/1585868) for a better faster solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because the time complexity of your algorithm is pretty much O(n^2). [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) created a better algorithm that will prevent your browser from freezing. 
Here is one way of doing it:

```
var exceptions = {
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  5: 5,
  7: 7
}

var primeSieve = function (start, end) {
  var result = [];
  for (start; start < end; start++) {
    if (start in exceptions) result.push(start);
    if (start > 1 && start % 2 !== 0 && start % 3 !== 0 && start % 5 !== 0 && start % 7 !== 0) {
      result.push(start);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

You can obviously make this look prettier, but I just did it quickly so you can get the point. I hope this helps! Let me know if you have further questions.